# Why is `PlotStyle->`List of colors not honored in this example?

Tags: plotting, legending

This happens in version 12.3:

Why is `PlotStyle->`List of colors not honored in this example? Why is there only one legend?

```
Plot[Table[{-273.15 + c v^(1 - kappa)}, {kappa, 1.1, 1.4, 0.1}]
, {v, 1/6, 6}
, PlotLabel -> "Adiabaten"
, PlotRange -> All
, PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Green, Blue}
, PlotLegends -> {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}
, AxesLabel -> {"Volumen", "\[Degree]C"}
]
```

But if I give the functions to be plotted explicitly without Table, it works as expected:

```
Plot[{-273.15+c v^(1-1.1), -273.15+c v^(1-1.2),-273.15+c v^(1-1.3),-273.15+c v^(1-1.4)}
, {v, 1/6, 6}
, PlotLabel -> "Adiabaten"
, PlotRange -> All
, PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Green, Blue}
, PlotLegends -> {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}
, AxesLabel -> {"Volumen", "\[Degree]C"}
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Plot has attribute `HoldAll` and evaluates the function(s) to be plotted  only after assigning specific numerical values to the variable of them (in my case: `v`).

In order to make my first example work, one has to put `Table[...]` into `Evaluate`:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[{-273.15 + c v^(1 - kappa)}, {kappa, 1.1, 1.4, 0.1}]]
, {v, 1/6, 6}
, PlotLabel -> "Adiabaten"
, PlotRange -> All
, PlotStyle -> {Red, Orange, Green, Blue}
, PlotLegends -> {1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.4}
, AxesLabel -> {"Volumen", "\[Degree]C"}
]
```